# it begs to be made fun of

Tags: meaning

*The power of the Doors’ music is that it is so unabashedly arty that **it begs to be made fun of**, especially by older people or those who went through Doors periods themselves and are now into Steely Dan or Animal Collective or some other less embarrassing musical endeavor.*

https://www.poetryfoundation.org/articles/69750/when-youre-strange

Can you explain to me for what the music of The Doors begs. The passage in bold does not make much sense to me. Does it mean that the music of The Doors urges the listener to ridicule it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: "now into Steely Dan"? God, how old is this article? Is it still relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often say that  behavior is tantamount to *asking* for something.

> Act that way, go ahead. You're *asking* for a punch in the nose.
>
> The music is so pretentious it *begs* to be ridiculed.